# How can I hide the entire repeater when its empty from html tag

Tags: asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

How can I hide the entire Repeater when the repeater is empty (have no data)

without using code behind?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I hide a repeater in ASP.NET C# if the DataSource contains no items?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327151/how-can-i-hide-a-repeater-in-asp-net-c-sharp-if-the-datasource-contains-no-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add to the repeater's attributes this code, keep in mind you have to change 'RepeaterName'to the current repeater:

```
Visible='<%# RepeaterName.Items.Count != 0 %>
```

Example of how the start tag of a repeater will be:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterName" runat="server" Visible='<%# RepeaterName.Items.Count != 0 %>'>
```

** Sorry if this is a duplicate, I have been trying to find the best answer for a long time, and I just found it.